# Solving: How many shops are open at a certain time?

Tags: algorithm, scheduling

I was posed this question at an interview and never really came up with a great solution. Does anyone have an "optimum" solution? Where the target is efficiency and being able to deal with large input.

**Material Provided:**

I am given a long list of shops and their opening/closing times (say 1000).

**The Problem:**

For a given time of day, return how many of the shops are open

**Example Data:**

```
Sainsburys 10:00 23:00
Asda 02:00 18:00
Walmart 17:00 22:00
```

**Example In/Out**

```
Input | Output
12:00 | 2
22:00 | 1 (walmart shut @ 22:00)
17:30 | 3
```

The two parts of the problem are how to store the data and how to efficiently get the answer, I guess how you're reading the input etc doesn't really matter.

Thanks for your time and insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a stab:

```
//First, we turn the time input into an int and then compare it to the open and
//closing time ints to determine if the shop is open. We'l use 10:00 in this example.
//get magic time int
int magicTimeInt = CInt("10:00".Replace(":",""));
int openstorecount = 0;
foreach(var shoptime in ShopTimesList)//SHopTImesList is the list of shop names and times
{
    string[] theShop = shoptime.Split(" ");
    if( CInt(theshop[1].ToString().Replace(":", "")) < magicTimeInt 
    && 
    CInt(theshop[2].ToString().Replace(":", "")) > magicTimeInt)
    {
        openstorecount++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("10:00 | " + openstorecount.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a database:

```
TABLE shops (
 name VARCHAR,
 open TIME,
 close TIME
)

SELECT count(*) AS number_of_shops FROM shops WHERE [input_time] BETWEEN open AND close
```

To prevent the query from counting walmart (in your example), you could add a second to open and substract a second from close (or some minutes to give anyone the chance to buy something).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it Java:

```
class Shop {
    String name;
    Time opening, closing;

    Shop(String name; Time opening, Time closing){
        this.name = name;
        this.opening = opening;
        this.closing = closing;
    }

    public boolean isOpen(Time time){
        return opening.before(time) && closing.after(time)
    }
}
```

Add code to trim date information from the time values, and just make a collection of all the stores, iterate through, and incerment your count for each open one.